# Hover event not triggering properly in MS Edge

Tags: jquery, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a pretty big project and have managed to get everything working on most all browsers except for MS Edge.  No supprise there but I really need this hover effect to work.  The hover event triggers once in Edge and then stops working entirely.  In addition, it never even calls the function I set up.  I have watered down the basic function and related code, made a demo and included it here as well as setting up a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8cqw60Le/4/.  Almost forgot, I'm running Windows 10 fully updated, the code is running Jquery 3.2.0 and it's setting up on "onDomready" though nothing else I tried worked either.  Please help.  I'm stumped.

html:

```
<div id="hover_test_div" style="width:300px; height:300px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">Hover over this.</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#hover_test_div").hover(function() {
    alert ("Over");
    trigger_function();
}, function() {
    alert ("Out");
    trigger_function();
});

function trigger_function() {
    alert ("Event triggered.")
}
```

I have looked into and tried the suggestion made and still does not work in Edge.  This is what I tried in jsfiddle.

```
$( "#hover_test_div" ).on( "mouseover mouseout", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

It works great in everything but Edge where it triggers once and then nothing.  This is the new JSFiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/8cqw60Le/8/

Comment: the hover method is depricated - and was depricated before the release of Edge.

It is not surprising that it dont work. Use the .on method instead to ensure compatibility with edge.

More info: http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I read up on the method and have tried your suggestion and it is reacting the same way.  I edited the post with the updated tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Edge when you call the `alert` function in a `mouseover` event handler. I did some *very* quick searching and didn't see a writeup anywhere, so it may be worth writing it up.

Nature of the bug: Calling `alert` in the `mouseover` event handler seems to confuse Edge's selection/mouse model. I noticed that after the `alert` you couldn't select text anymore.

**To dup:**

1. Move the mouse over the box.
2. Click OK on the alert box.
3. Try to select the "Hover over this." text. **Nothing happens.**

**Solution:**

Do the `alert` in a `setTimeout`. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwrdcn5e/) that should work.

---

**Edit**: I wrote up a bug report [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11329025/).

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I was beginning to think I was going crazy.  I have, since posting originally, figured out a workaround.  It is much less elegant and compact as yours but I don't want to reprogram it again.. LOL.  I up voted your answer but don't have enough rep yet.  Thank you again.

Comment: @KentTorkelson Glad I could help. If you feel this answer is enough then marking it as Accepted will help the community triage what questions need better answers (it also gives me sweet sweet internet points). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.